# How Can I initialize React-Native project on Github CodeSpace(Linux)

Tags: android, react-native, codespaces, github-codespaces

I want to start my RN project on github codespace. But there is the problem to initialize RN project.
My codespace's program version is as follow.
[pic:program version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhaQK.png)

And I install android command line tools and sdk correctly(in my thought). [pic:android-sdk, cmdline tools version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gDp1.png) / [pic:PATH which I added in bashrc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vz6pp.png)

But when I command `$ npx react-native init projectName`, an error occurs.
And this is the error massage. [pic:error massage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKamE.png)

I didn't install RN in global, and the directory which error massage said it doesn't exist, is truly exist.

(ex:'/workspaces/NRC_CloneApp/projectName/android/app/src/debug/java/com/helloworld/ReactNativeFlipper.java' )

I really don't know how can I resolve this problem.

1. I heard install RN global is not good idea, so I didn't install RN in global.
2. I heard use low version of RN, so I use this commands `$ npx react-native init projectName --version 0.68.2`
3. I heard use option as follow, `npx --ignore-existing react-native init projectName`

But all didn't works...